# pytorch optim.SGD with momentum how to check "velocity"?

Tags: pytorch

I have a noob question: from the SGD [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.SGD.html) they provided the equation of SGD with momentum, which indicates that apart from current gradient `weight.grad`, we also need to save the velocity from the previous step (something like `weight.prev_v`?). I know `nn.Parameter` object has `.data` and `.grad` attributes, but does it also saves a `.prev_v`? Do you know how pytorch works? Thanks!

Edit: Basically I'd like to know where does pytorch save velocity from the previous step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are stored inside the state attribute of the optimizer. In the case of [`torch.optim.SGD`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.SGD.html) the momentum values are stored a dictionary under the `'momentum_buffer'` key, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/sgd.py#L148).

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> m = nn.Linear(10,10)
>>> optim = torch.optim.SGD(m.parameters(), lr=1.e-3, momentum=.9)
>>> m(torch.rand(1, 10)).mean().backward()
>>> optim.step()

>>> optim.state
defaultdict(dict, {0: {}, Parameter containing: ...})

>>> list(optim.state.values())[0]
{'momentum_buffer': tensor([...])}
```

Comment: Thanks again Ivan! just to be more clear, if I use, say,  1GB to store gradients of all parameters, then if I enable momentum I need another 1GB to save previous velocity of all paramters?

Comment: Optimizer's states are often overlooked but they do take quite a lot of memory. In this case, yes SGD's state takes as much memory as the gradients themselves!